# mySQL query results being trimmed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this mySQL query to get a list of all the column names in my table. It works fine except that `values` is cut off at 341 characters, so I'm not getting the full list.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT( `COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR ',') as values FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='mytable' AND `TABLE_NAME`='tablename'
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can handle it?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` has a limit of default 1024 characters but it can be increased by following docs

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Any idea why mine would be set at 341?

Comment: @jonmrich What does `SELECT @@group_concat_max_len` return?

Comment: You can see the limit by running something like `show variables like 'group_concat_max_len%'`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It returns: `[{"@@group_concat_max_len":"1024"}]` Not sure why my results are cut off at 341 then. Also, not quite sure how to use this `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=your_value_here;`. Can I just add it to my PHP file that needs this longer default?

Comment: You can execute a query in your PHP as `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=your_value_here;` to set the value you need. Are you seeing the value truncated at 341  if you just ran your query in a regular MySQL client, isolated from your PHP code?

Comment: I ran the query in a "desktop" mySQL client (SequelPRO) and got the same thing back (341 character). Can you give me a query example? Still struggling with this part.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Figured out a query and updated the length, so looks like I'm in business. Thanks!